# react call a function from ReactDOM.render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in my index.js File I have this:

```
const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
        i18n: i18nReducer
    }),
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
syncTranslationWithStore(store)
store.dispatch(loadTranslations(translationsObject));
store.dispatch(setLocale('de'));
```

with this code the default language is set to greman. Now I want to make a Button in ReactDOM.render where I can chang the languge, at best with a stahet (de/en)

What I have done is this:

```
function changeLanguage() {
    function handleClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        store.dispatch(setLocale('de'));
    }
}
```

and the in the ReactDOM

```
 <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <div>
            <div className="sidebararound">
                <div className="sidebar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a className="fa fa-language fa-2x" onClick={this.changeLanguage.handleClick.bind()} aria-hidden="true"></a></li>
```

But thats not working. I got a white page. Where is my mistake?

Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is here `this.changeLanguage.handleClick.bind()`, changeLanguage is not an object, Try with `function handleClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        store.dispatch(setLocale('de'));
    }` and `onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}`

Comment: its close. thanks. function is okay. But I have to change the onClick event to: `onClick={handleClick}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always a good practice to bind the events in constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
   ....
}

handleClick(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  store.dispatch(setLocale('de'));
}
```

and in the render method:

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
        <div>
            <div className="sidebararound">
                <div className="sidebar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a className="fa fa-language fa-2x" onClick={this.handleClick} aria-hidden="true"></a></li>
```